# Factory Girl sets wrong value for auto-increment id in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, auto-increment, factory-bot

I have two dependent models with one to many association

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

in my DBMS `post_id` in `users` table is defined as a foreign key

I wrote two cucumber scenarios - in first I(with factory_girl help) create two users and in second I also want to create two users but creation fails because `factory_girl` builds dependent `post` records with `id` set to one however in previous scenario two records in `posts` table were created and deleted so `id` value should start from `3` and not from `1`. I used `pry` to debug this process and spotted that if I use `FactoryGirl.build( :post )` it sets value properly but if I use `FactoryGirl.build( :user )` value of the associated `post.id` is always `1`. How can I make it buld records with proper `id`?

**EDIT**

```
FactoryGirl.define do 

  sequence :composite_id do |n| 
    "F98F3806-#{sprintf("%04X", n)}-4C96-879C-2C6F38213D8E"
  end

  # Post 
  factory :post do
    sequence( :post_id ) { |n| "#{n}" }
    some_field "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a"
    ...
  end

  # User
  factory :user do
    user_id { FactoryGirl.generate( :composite_id )}
    association :post_id, :factory => :post
    ...
  end

end
```

Comment: What does your factories file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be `association :post`. FactoryGirl will figure out the ID field.